# Why is InDesign inserting a space after my lines when the lines in the Word file have no space after?

Tags: adobe-indesign

After I place my Word file into InDesign, the software is adding space after lines that shouldn't have any. In Word, some lines have no space after. But now in InDesign, they do. Is there a way to prevent this? It looks like every line that has a hard return now gains the same amount of space after.

Comment: You mean why `ABC[return]` has the same height as `ABC[return]DEF` and not the same height as just `ABC`?

Comment: I’ve read this four times now, and I still can’t figure out what exactly it is you’re describing. Could you try to illustrate with some screen shots from both programs? Make sure to turn on ‘Show invisible characters’ so we can see precisely what’s actually there.

Comment: Word sometimes includes odd breaks: check to see if someone is using shift+enter. In find+replace, the "special character" is `^L`

Comment: Thank you for your desire to help, Janus Bahs Jaquet. I believe we figured it out, although I know screen shots would have been helpful.

Comment: Yorik, thank you for the advice. Although there weren't any shift+enter, I did have those on another project that I had to fix. Thank you for your comment and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your default paragraph style in InDesign includes a space after.

Remove this spacing in the paragraph style definition and your text spacing should be the same as it was in Word.

However, most people who do typesetting for a living prefer to include spacing as part of the paragraph styling rather than adding additional paragraph returns between paragraphs.

Comment: If I remove the spacing in the paragraph style definition, then will all paragraphs come in without any space after or will they maintain their formatting from Word? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you make the change to the paragraphs only, then any new text you add will have the same spacing that you have now. You need to make the change to the paragraph STYLE and then all new paragraph s should come in without the spacing.

Comment: I would show you an example, but I am answering from my phone and don't have my computer here. Sorry.

Comment: I will experiment with what you said, and thank you for the help! And so quickly too.